xslt to identify duplicates
I have an input file that looks like this:
<root>
    <row>
        <Supplier>SUPPLIER100</Supplier>
        <Action>Activate Account</Action>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Supplier>SUPPLIER200</Supplier>
        <Action>Activate Account</Action>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Supplier>SUPPLIER300</Supplier>
        <Action>Cancel Account</Action>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Supplier>SUPPLIER300</Supplier>
        <Action>Cancel Account</Action>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Supplier>SUPPLIER400</Supplier>
        <Action>Cancel Account</Action>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Supplier>SUPPLIER400</Supplier>
        <Action>Activate Account</Action>
    </row>
</root>

I am trying to write an xslt to identify unique nodes and report on the duplicate ones and looking to get an output like following. I was not able to generate the output. Any assistance would be really appreciated:
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<root>
    <row>
        <Supplier>SUPPLIER100</Supplier>
        <Action>Activate Account</Action>
        <Process>Yes</Process>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Supplier>SUPPLIER200</Supplier>
        <Action>Activate Account</Action>
        <Process>Yes</Process>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Supplier>SUPPLIER300</Supplier>
        <Action>Cancel Account</Action>
        <Process>Yes</Process>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Supplier>SUPPLIER400</Supplier>
        <Action/>
        <Process>No</Process>
        <ProcessingMessage>Multiple Actions Found</ProcessingMessage>
    </row>
</root>


Using grouping e.g. <xsl:template match="row"><xsl:copy><xsl:for-each-group select="row" group-by="Supplier"><xsl:choose><xsl:when test="distinct-values(current-group()/Action)[2]"> you can group rows on Supplier and you can then check whether there is more than one distinct Action in a group to output the result you want to output.
